# VBA copy / paste

Tags: vba, copy, paste

I have 80 machines, and 80 tabs in an excel workbook. On each tab there is a list of one month's dates in column (A) with an entry in a column (C) of how many accumulative hours the machine worked during the month. So, the daily increase is between 0 (if the machine was out of order) and 24.

I am looking for a solution to automate the record in cases where the daily addition is zero hours. In that event the accumulated total from the previous day must be copied to the next day's cell in column (C).

I'm sure it's pretty straightforward but can't work it out and I didn't find a similar question having been asked before on the web.

Thanks in advance

Ian

Comment: "take the labour out of dragging the values" would require some explanation. Do you think it can be done using a worksheet function?

Comment: OK, I have 80 machines, and 80 tabs in an excel workbook, each day the machines work a maximum of 24 hours, if they are broken down for 24 hours, I want to hit a button to take yesterdays hours, put them in todays cell below and then scroll to the next tab. I.e. if 30 of the 80 machines are broken down without change the following day it would save me time dragging the hours down manually 30 times.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will allow you to enter the total number of hours for each day. It will add the number you enter to the previous total and replace your entry with the sum. You can enter zero, resulting in a new total which is unchanged from the previous. After entry the code will jump to the next sheet, selecting the cell to be filled for the day and highlighting the date green. If there is already an entry the highlight will be pink.

If there were no entries during previous days the presumption will be that there were no hours worked and the record completed accordingly above the row you enter current hours in. You can't enter negative numbers of hours or hours in excess of 24. You can't enter in cells where there are entries below the cell you want to modify, even if that cell is blank.

The code consists of two components. The first installment needs to go into a standard code module. It's one that doesn't exist in your workbook. Find the way to add a module. If its name is like `Module1` its correct. Paste the code below into it. I would prefer to rename the module (perhaps like "STO_200408") but it isn't necessary.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                                ' worksheet navigation
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2                 ' modify if your data don't start in row 2
    NwsDate = 1                         ' date column: 1 identifies column A
    NwsHours = 3
End Enum

Sub WorksheetActivate(Ws As Worksheet)
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020

    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Ws.Columns(NwsDate).Find(Date, , , xlWhole)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "I didn't find today's date on the """ & _
               Ws.Name & """." & vbCr & _
               "It may have been entered using an invalid format.", _
               vbInformation, "Missing or invalid date"
    Else
        WorksheetDeactivate Ws              ' remove existing highlight
        With Rng.Resize(1, NwsHours)
            .Interior.Color = IIf(.Cells(NwsHours).Value, 13431551, 14348258)
            .Cells(NwsHours).Select
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function WorksheetChange(Target As Range) As Boolean
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020
    ' return Not True if accumulator couldn't be set

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Hours As Double
    Dim Accu As Double
    Dim R As Long

    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Function

        With .Worksheet
            R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsDate).End(xlUp).Row
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsHours), _
                             .Cells(R, NwsHours))
        End With

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If GetAccu(Accu, Target.Worksheet, .Row) Then
                Hours = Val(.Value)
                ' modify if you record time hours:-
                If (Hours > 24) Or (Hours < 0) Then
                    MsgBox "Please enter a positive value smaller or equal to 24 hours.", _
                           vbExclamation, "Invalid number of hours"
                    GoTo SideExit
                End If
                .Value = Accu + Val(.Value)
                WorksheetChange = True
            Else
SideExit:
                .Select
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Function

Sub WorksheetDeactivate(Ws As Worksheet)
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020

    Dim Rng As Range

    With Ws
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsDate), _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsDate).End(xlUp) _
                                .Offset(0, NwsHours - 1))
        Rng.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetAccu(Accu As Double, _
                         Ws As Worksheet, _
                         ByVal Rt As Long) As Boolean
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020
    ' 'Accu' is a return variable
    ' return Not True if no b/f total could be determined

    Dim R As Long

    With Ws
        If .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsHours).End(xlUp).Row > Rt Then
            MsgBox "There may be no entries in the 'Hours' column" & vbCr & _
                   "below the entry now being processed." & vbCr & _
                   "Remove existing entries and repeat.", _
                   vbExclamation, "Record irregularity"
        Else
            GetAccu = True
            With .Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsHours)
                If Len(.Value) = 0 Then .Value = 0
            End With

            R = Rt
            Do
                R = R - 1
                With .Cells(R, NwsHours)
                    If Len(.Value) Then
                        Accu = Val(.Value)
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                End With
            Loop While R > NwsFirstDataRow

            For R = (R + 1) To (Rt - 1)
                .Cells(R, NwsHours).Value = Accu
            Next R
        End If
    End With
End Function

Sub GotoNextSheet()
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020

    Dim Idx As Integer

    Idx = ActiveSheet.Index + 1
    If Idx > Worksheets.Count Then Idx = 1
    Worksheets(Idx).Activate
End Sub
```

Next, find the code module belonging to a sheet on which you keep the hours for a machine. If you double-click on the worksheet's name in VB Editor's Project explorer the correct code sheet will open. Paste the code you find below into that sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020
    WorksheetActivate ActiveSheet
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020
    If WorksheetChange(Target) Then GotoNextSheet
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    ' Variatus @STO 08 Apr 2020
    WorksheetDeactivate ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

This code connects what happens on that worksheet to the code in `Module1`. You can now make entries in column C of that sheet and see the action. I suggest you do so to test both the code and its location.

Since you want action on all your 80 sheets the same code should be pasted to the code sheet of all 80. Note that the code will be copied to the copy of a worksheet if you create it using right-click on the tab but not if you select the entire sheet and paste it to a new sheet. So, to start a new month you can create copies from a template that includes the code and will not have to worry about copying the code separately.

Once all your 80 sheets have the event code you are set to go. Note that the code will jump to the next sheet after each entry and loop back to the first when it hits the last. You will know when you're done when you see the color of the highlight changed to pink and the selected cell already containing a sum.